# Abstract method restriction control for derived classes

Tags: java, class, abstract

Is it possible for an abstract base class to have abstract methods where only certain derived classes have access to certain abstract methods? What I'm trying to do is limit possible methods being able to be called from different inherited classes. Here is an example of my question:

```
public abstract Foo
{
    ...
    public abstract void fooMethod1(int num1);
    public abstract void fooMethod2(int num2);
}

public Bar1 extends Foo // This class shouldn't be able to access fooMethod2()
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void fooMethod1(int num1)
    {
        System.out.println((num1 * 5));
    }
}

public Bar2 extends Foo // This class has no restrictions
{
     ...
     @Override
     public void fooMethod1(int num1)
     {
          System.out.println((num1 * 10));
     }

     @Override
     public void fooMethod2(int num2)
     {
          System.out.println((num2 * 5));
     }
```

Comment: Other than private variables, a subclass will have access to all the members of the superclass if it extends the superclass.

Comment: Probably `fooMethod2` method doesn't belong in `Foo`.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your public abstract methods must be override in every sub class.
What yo can do:

1. Split `Foo` abstract class to two classes: `BaseFoo` and `ExtendedFoo` where `ExtendedFoo` should extends `BaseFoo`, so `Bar1` extends `BaseFoo` and `Bar2` extends `ExtendedFoo`.
2. Override the unwanted method to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` so if this method is called it will throw a (meaningful) exception.

I would go with first approach.

Answer (score 2):

That would be like this. However, this might not be what you really want. It depends on your real requirements.

```
public abstract class Foo
{

}

public abstract class FooMeth1 extends Foo {
    public abstract void fooMethod1(int num1);

}

public abstract class FooMeth2 extends FooMeth1 {
    public abstract void fooMethod2(int num2);
}

public class Bar1 extends FooMeth1 // This class shouldn't be able to access fooMethod2()
{
    @Override
    public void fooMethod1(int num1)
    {
        System.out.println((num1 * 5));
    }
}

public class Bar2 extends FooMeth2 // This class has no restrictions
{
     @Override
     public void fooMethod1(int num1)
     {
          System.out.println((num1 * 10));
     }

     @Override
     public void fooMethod2(int num2)
     {
          System.out.println((num2 * 5));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, all your public abstract method in super classes are visible to subclasses.
More than this, it is mandatory to all subclasses to implement all abstract methods.

For your need, I suggest to have another class in between Foo and Bar1 where you make implement a desired method.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do by putting Bar2 in the same package and Bar1 in a different package and making the methods package-protected and public respectively. Or you can create an annotation and generate code to check the caller via reflection brute-force.

Comment: And do you mean "override" with "access"? If you do , that is impossible to do via normal methods. since it is either final or it is not. You could do some reflection magic so that you make the original method "final" and then call the overridable method only if the current class is a specific class, but that is nasty.

Answer (score 0):

To add my own two cents, I would say instead of using a super class, you make two interfaces. ie `Foo1` and `Foo2`. each interface will contain one of the methods. Then you can have `Bar1` and `Bar2` implementing `Foo1` and `Foo2` respectively. The benefit of this method is that you can have a Class `Bar3` that implements Both interfaces, whereas, with Abstract classes, you can only extend one Superclass.

Answer (score 0):

If the Foo class only has abstract methods, you could seperate the Foo class in 2 interfaces, then implement whichever interface is required in bar1 and bar2. Alternatively split the methods that are only required in bar1 into an interface and leave the rest in foo